# Копирование объекта с последующим изменением

Tags: javascript

подскажите как правильно сделать копию объекта которую я смогу изменять и в то же время эти изменения не будут касаться оригинала?
Вот для примера, я использую объект:

```
var original = {someNumber : 1,
         someZero : 0,
         oPets : {tishka : 1,
                  sharik : 1}
         }
var copy = original; // делаю копию (и как я подозреваю делаю связку их друг с другом)
copy.oPets.sharik = "doggy";
// copy.oPets.sharik === "doggy" // true
// original.oPets.sharik === "doggy" // true
```

Comment: ошибка в том, что при присваивании копия объекта не делается

Comment: @Grundy но ведь присваиваю я же не оригиналу, а копии которая была уже до этого создана

Comment: неа, вы не правы

Comment: @Grundy я уже понял)

Comment: @Grundy я уже вижу что вариантов море просто, и джиквери и джейсон.парс и др.. не думал что на чистом джс нету решения в 1 клик) работаю сейчас с ангуляром поэтому angular.copy() сейчас отлично помог в решении

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Для начала стоит отметить, что все объекты в JS присваиваются и предаются **по ссылке**. Это значит, что делая:

```
var copy = original;
```

вы на самом деле помещаете *ссылку* на `original` в переменную `copy`.

В зависимости от дополнительных условий, существует несколько вариантов решения клонирования объектов в JavaScript.

1. Если вам нужна *поверхностная* копия (один уровень вложенности) объекта, можно использовать ES6 [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

   ```
   var copy = Object.assign({}, original);
   ```
2. Если вы не планируете использовать конструкции, вроде [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) и [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) на копии, можно задать оригинал как *прототип* копии. Делается это вот так:

   ```
   var copy = Object.create(original);
   ```

   К сожалению, этот метод тоже создает только *поверхностную* копию объекта, но позволяет сэкономить немного памяти на свойствах, которые не будут переопределены.
3. Если ваш исходный объект может быть безболезненно сериализован в JSON (не содержит функций, сложных объектов, вроде `Date` и циклических ссылок), то можно использовать хак с сериализацией-десериализацией:

   ```
   var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
   ```
4. Если использование сторонних библиотек допустимо, то можно использовать существующие реализации глубокого копирования. В [lodash](https://lodash.com/), например, есть метод [`_.cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep):

   ```
   var copy = _.cloneDeep(original);
   ```

   Похожие методы есть во многих библиотеках. Например в jQuery есть метод [`jQuery.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN):

   ```
   // Первый аргумент указывает на глубину копирования
   var copy = jQuery.extend(true, {}, original);
   ```

   Вам стоит проверить документацию к используемым библиотекам, возможно там есть свой метод для глубокого копирования.
5. Если ни один из методов выше не подошел, вам придется реализовать свой собственный вариант функции глубокого копирования. Как сделать это эффективно лучше посмотреть в исходниках одной из существующих библиотек глубокого копирования.

Comment: как 6 вариант хотел бы еще добавить angular.copy(), для тех кто работает с ангуляром

Comment: @YoroDiallo, это входит в 4 пункт - использование сторонних библиотек

Comment: @YoroDiallo, это, по-сути, вариант 4. Перечислять все известные методы клонирования из всех известных библиотек - это совсем жесть =)

Comment: согласен) туплю

Comment: _К сожалению, этот метод тоже создает только поверхностную копию объекта, но позволяет сэкономить немного памяти на свойствах, которые не будут переопределены_ - это к JSON.parse/JSON.stringify относится? он же как раз полную копию делает, а не только первого уровня

Comment: @Grundy, вы правы, это относится к `Object.create`. Исправил

Answer (score 1):

Если используется jQuery

```
var original = {a:1, b:{c:3}}
var cloned = {};
jQuery.extend(true, cloned, original);
cloned.b.c = 10;
console.log(original);
```

Если нет - смотрим на популярные статьи на буржуйском SO 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: спасибо за ссылку!! а по jq вроде ж  ".clone() method in jQuery only clones DOM elements"

Comment: точно, спасибо за указания ошибки. Сейчас поправлю пост

Answer (score 0):

```
var original = {
    someNumber : 1,
    someZero : 0,
    oPets: {tishka: 1, sharik: 1}
}

var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));

copy.oPets.sharik = "doggy";

console.log(original.oPets.sharik); // 1
console.log(copy.oPets.sharik); // doggy
```

Comment: Переводим объект в json строку и парсим

Comment: Этот комментарий лучше в ответ добавить

Comment: Не будет работать, если объект содержит поле-функцию или объект `Date` или циклическую ссылку

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, `f: function() { ... }` ?

Comment: @Doofy, `JSON.stringify({t:function(){}})` -> `"{}"`

Comment: @Grundy, ну да, с функциями не прокатит

Comment: @Doofy, равно как и с объектами `Date` и циклическими ссылками =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, да да, я вкурсе, просто в вопросе небыло ничего про функции. Учитывая что там только объекты, можно воспользоваться этим вариантом

Comment: @Doofy, просто о таких ограничениях метода стоит в явном виде предупреждать в ответе.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, с `Date` по другой причине :-) если функции тупо не сериализуются, то `Date` не десериализуются :-) и да, я догадываюсь, что ты знал об этом :):):)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, не подумал, про `var copy = Object.create(original);` сам только узнал, хороший вопрос)

Comment: @Grundy, знал конечно. Кстати, интересно как будут вести себя другие сложные типы данных, например DOMElement =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, никак - они не сериализуются

Comment: Стал частенько видеть от Grundy в комментах "никак" :)

Comment: @Doofy, потому что проще сразу сказать, чем долго пытаться объяснить - почему :-D