# Как перебрать все свойства объекта, преобразовать их неким образом и вернуть преобразованный объект?

Tags: javascript

Как перебрать все свойства объекта, преобразовать их неким образом и вернуть преобразованный объект?

есть объект такой

```
"object": {
    "user": "admin",
    "date": "14877890",
    "last": "SKIPPED"
}
```

Нужно преобразовать `date` в дату и получить новый объект

Comment: Может `let copy = Object.assign({}, object); copy.date = функция_для_преобразования_даты(copy.date);`?

Comment: @diraria, assign Только верхний уровень копирует, если будет вложенный объект, то при изменении его полей, изменения будут заметны в обоих объектах

Comment: @Grundy, да, точно.

Comment: @Grundy, на ruSO есть вопрос про глубокое копирование?

Comment: @diraria, да, есть: [копирование объекта с последующим изменением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540089/186999)

Answer (score 4):

Вот пример с функцией [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) для прохождения по объекту, и преоброзования `timestamp` в [date](https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime)

```js
var object = {
    "user": "admin",
    "date": "14877890",
    "last": "SKIPPED"
}

function timestamp2date(timestamp) { 
    var theDate = new Date(timestamp * 1000); 
    return theDate.toGMTString(); 
}

Object.keys(object).map(function(objectKey, index) {
    var value = object[objectKey];
    if(objectKey == 'date'){
        console.log(timestamp2date(value));
    }
});
```

Comment: а как вот мне через спред оператор создать копию объекта и поменять в нем только одно свойство, не перебирая их все? без if

Comment: @werty задайте полноценный вопрос и я отвечу вам

Comment: я созадал отдельный вопрос 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688029/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0