# Как поменять значение у одного свойства объекта?

Tags: javascript

Как вместо этого сделать копию объекта через spread оператор, и у копии поменять значение одного свойства. Нужно поменять только `date`

```js
var object = {
  "user": "admin",
  "date": "14877890",
  "last": "SKIPPED"
}

function timestamp2date(timestamp) {
  var theDate = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
  return theDate.toGMTString();
}

Object.keys(object).map(function(objectKey, index) {
  var value = object[objectKey];
  if (objectKey == 'date') {
    console.log(timestamp2date(value));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы так хотели? я правильно понял вас?

```js
var object = {
    "user": "admin",
    "date": "14877890",
    "last": "SKIPPED"
}
var copy = Object.assign({}, object);

function timestamp2date(timestamp) { 
    var theDate = new Date(timestamp * 1000); 
    return theDate.toGMTString(); 
}
copy.date = timestamp2date(copy.date);

console.log(copy.date);
```

Comment: мне нужно переписать свойство

вот я сделал, но как-то некрасиво

 const object2 = {...object};

        object['date'] = new Date(object['date']).toLocaleString('ru');

Comment: как еще упростить

Comment: @werty ну вот так, что в этом особенного?

Comment: @werty там всего несколько простых строк кода, что в нем еще упростить?

Comment: хорошо. спасибо

Comment: @werty не за что