# Как скопировать объект в другой, но с другими названиями полей?

Tags: javascript

Есть объект

```
personalData: {
  surname: '',
  name: '',
  region: '',
  city: '',
  country: '',
  birthdate: '',
  snails: '',
  education: '',
  phoneMobile: '',
  email: '',
}
```

Мне нужно передать объект, только с другими названиями полей.

Как мне скопировать этот объект в другой, но с другими названиями полей?

Через спред оператор как-нибудь

Comment: через spread оператор никак не получится.

Comment: чем данный вопрос отличается от уже заданных: [Как перебрать все свойства объекта, преобразовать их неким образом и вернуть преобразованный объект?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/687904/186999) и [Как поменять значение у одного свойства объекта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688029/186999)?

Comment: если я создаем новый объект со свойствами
const personalDataForApi = {
    BirthDate: '',
    Education: '',
    Email: '',
    FirstName: '',
    IsSnilsExist: '',
    LastName: '',
    MiddleName: '',
    PhoneNumber: ''
}

и склонирую тот объект в этот?

Comment: Я не понял твой комментарий. Дополнения делай в самом вопросе. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring раздел "Деструктуризация объекта"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если пойти по ссылке предложенной @greybutton то там следующие:

```
'use strict';

let options = {
  title: "Меню",
  width: 100,
  height: 200
};

let {width: w, height: h, title} = options;

alert(title);  // Меню
alert(w);      // 100
alert(h);      // 200
```