# Клонирование и изменение элемента в массиве

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Помогите скопировать и изменить элемент в массиве.
Когда копирую все нормально, но как только я обновляю изменяется 2 элемента.
Тот который скопировал и тот с которого cкопировал.

Имеется вот такой пример:

```
$(function() {
var element = [
{"id":1, "name":"test1"},
{"id":2, "name":"test2"},
{"id":3, "name":"test3"},
{"id":4, "name":"test4"},
{"id":5, "name":"test5"}
];

$("#clone").on("click", function(){
  element.push(element[1]);
});

$("#update").on("click", function(){
  element[5]["name"] += " update"; //Изменяется новый элемент и элемент с id 2 
  console.log(element);
});

});
```

Так же пробую изменить:

```
element.push(element[1]);
```

на:

```
element[element.length]=element[1].slice();
```

Получаю ошибку:
element[1].slice is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var element = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "test2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "test3"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "test4"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "test5"
    }
  ];

  var elementCopy;

  $("#clone").on("click", function() {
    elementCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
    elementCopy.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element[1])));
  });

  $("#update").on("click", function() {
    elementCopy[5]["name"] += " update"; //Изменяется новый элемент и элемент с id 2 
    console.log({
      'Исходный массив ': element
    });
    console.log({
      'Копия массива ': elementCopy
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clone">Clone</div>
<div id="update">Update</div>
```

Comment: А как если изменить исходный массив?

Comment: @JonyKook измениться только исходный само собой. Когда копируете массив через `slice` исходный массив не меняется — на момент копирования вы получаете два разных массива с одинаковыми значениями.

Comment: @JonyKook почему минус? Скажите, что в вопросе я не правильно понял — поправлю. Или это модераторы?..

Comment: Это не я минус поставил

Comment: @JonyKook блин, жалко голоса не вижу пока... Спасибо. _Метод [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) добавляет один или более элементов в конец массива и возвращает новую длину массива._

Comment: я попробовал ваш способ, меняется также новый элемент и тот с которого копировали! а нужно изменить только новый, не могу понять почему меняются оба...

Comment: @JonyKook всё. Это я туплю. У вас массив же из объектов состоит... Извиняюсь.

Comment: @JonyKook вроде так. Изменил код. Тогда модераторы правы — от части на этот вопрос уже есть ответ.

Comment: @JonyKook `elementCopy.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element[1])));`, чтобы в новый массив копировалась не ссылка на этот объект `element[1]`, а именно копия. Если вам так нужно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы очень помогли!!

Comment: @JonyKook Пожалуйста! Вам ссылку на связанные материалы ещё добавили — [Копирование объекта с последующим изменением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540073/Копирование-объекта-с-последующим-изменением) — прочтите, будет полезно.