# Слияние двух объектов

Tags: javascript

Возникла необходимость объединения 2-х объектов в один, с соблюдением некоторых правил:

- Итоговый объект должен быть независим (при изменении его свойств,
  свойства исходных объектов меняться не должны и наоборот)
- Слияние должно быть глубоким
- Исходные объекты делятся на source и target. Target содержит все
  свойства, которые могут присутствовать в итоговом объекте, если такое
  свойство есть в source, то в итоговый попадает значение из него,
  иначе из target.
- Свойствами объектов могут быть любые типы.

При решении задачи, на ум приходит разве что рекурсивное копирование свойств из target в новый объект с проверкой есть ли такое свойство в source

```
function objectsMerge(source, target) {
    var result = {};
    for (var key in target) {
      if (target.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(target[key]) === '[object Object]') {
          result[key] = objectsMerge(source[key], target[key]);
        } else {
          result[key] = key in source ? source[key] : target[key];
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Остается одна деталь - если свойство объекта массив... 
Можно сделать проверку на это и в цикле скопировать все его ключи, а если ключ массив или объект....
Подскажите как можно более менее оптимально решить данную задачу?

Comment: По-моему, деталей тут осталось ещё довольно много; как на счёт рекурсивных объектов? Посмотрите в сторону [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) - слияние, но не глубокое. Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540073

Comment: И да, проверку, что вам пришёл объект, делают обычно так: `typeof a == 'object'`

Comment: @mymedia  В том то и дело что `Object.assign` не глубокое слияние, `typeof == 'object'` -  `null, array` - это так же `object`

Answer (score 3):

Я бы вам посоветовал использовать библиотеку `lodash` для таких целей. Конкретно функцию `_.merge(object, [sources])` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge

Описание на сайте:

> This method is like _.assign except that it recursively merges own and inherited enumerable string keyed properties of source objects into the destination object. Source properties that resolve to undefined are skipped if a destination value exists. Array and plain object properties are merged recursively. Other objects and value types are overridden by assignment. Source objects are applied from left to right. Subsequent sources overwrite property assignments of previous sources.

Также можете покопаться в исходном коде https://github.com/lodash/lodash и скопировать оттуда эту функцию, и, может, в чем-то модернизировать.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь 
https://github.com/KyleAMathews/deepmerge

Нет смысла писать свой велосипед, когда есть неплохой готовый.
В случае, если вы работаете с frontend, собирайте webpackом

Comment: А причём здесь фронтенд и вебпак?

Comment: Притом, что это серверный пакет, рассчитанный на использование с нодой.

Comment: По-вашему его нельзя использовать на бэкенде без вебпака?

Comment: Я этого не писал. Перечитайте внимательно мои сообщения

Comment: Либо вы его поменяли, либо меня невероятно проглючило! Извиняюсь.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, не менял - посмотрите по истории правок:) ничего страшного, все ок:)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант решения 1 строчку, не будет работать в глубину, но для остальных случаев идеально:

```js
let a = {bbb: 2, ccc: 3};
let b = {ddd:4, eeee: 5, ccc: 6}

let d = {...a, ...b};
```

Comment: так автор же написал условия, что любые типы, даже объекты, полная независимость и глубокое копирование